# JavaFX WebView blocks GUI

Tags: javafx, webview

All it's ok when i open light weight's pages but when i wan't to open some bigger the GUI blocks and not responding until the site load's. I try to give it to background thread but it's not working.

MainWindowController:

```
WebControl webcontroller = new WebControl();
DatabaseControl datacontroller;

@FXML
private ToggleButton PowypadkoweBt;
@FXML
private ToggleButton UszkodzoneBt;
@FXML
private ToggleButton MailBt;
@FXML
private ToggleButton SMSBt;
@FXML
private Button SendBt;
@FXML
private ScrollPane WynikiScroll;
@FXML
private TableView DoneTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn CheckCol, OpisCol, LoginCol;
@FXML
private TextArea MessageArea;
@FXML
private WebView WebControl;
@FXML
private Button NEXT;
@FXML
private Button PREVIOUS;
@FXML
private Label PAGE;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    this.CheckCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<CellDataFeatures<UsedTableRow, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<UsedTableRow, Boolean> param) {
            return param.getValue().getCheckedProperty();
        }
    });
    this.CheckCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(this.CheckCol));
    this.CheckCol.setEditable(false);
    this.CheckCol.setMinWidth(50);
    this.CheckCol.setMaxWidth(50);

    this.OpisCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UsedTableRow, String>("Description"));
    this.LoginCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UsedTableRow, String>("Login"));

    ObservableList<UsedTableRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        datacontroller = new DatabaseControl();
        data.addAll(datacontroller.getRowsFromEntity());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setContentText("Nie udało się nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych. Błąd klasy.");
        alert.setHeaderText("Błąd klasy.");
        alert.setTitle("Błąd");
        alert.show();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setHeaderText("Błąd SQL.");
        alert.setContentText("Nie udało się nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych. Błąd SQL.");
        alert.setTitle("Błąd");
        alert.show();
    }

    this.DoneTable.setItems(data);

    this.WebControl.getEngine().load("http://otomoto.pl");
    this.PAGE.setText((this.webcontroller.getIteratorAuctions() + this.webcontroller.getIteratorItems() - 10) + " z " + this.webcontroller.getItemsIds().size());
   // loadNewSite();
    this.WebControl.autosize();

    this.WebControl.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            Double width = (Double) newValue;
            WebControl.setPrefWidth(width);
            WebControl.autosize();
        }
    });

    this.WebControl.requestLayout();
    this.WebControl.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
    this.WebControl.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.WebControl.getEngine().setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36");

    this.PowypadkoweBt.setSelected(true);
    this.UszkodzoneBt.setSelected(true);

}

@FXML
private void PowypadkoweAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (this.PowypadkoweBt.isSelected()) {
        this.webcontroller.refresh(true);
    } else {
        this.webcontroller.refresh(false);
    }

    loadNewSite();
}

@FXML
private void UszkodzoneAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
private void SMSAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
private void MailAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
private void SendAction(ActionEvent event) {
}

@FXML
private void PREVIOUSAction(ActionEvent event) {
    webcontroller.previousAuction();
    loadNewSite();
}

@FXML
private void NEXTAction(ActionEvent event) {
    webcontroller.nextAuction();
    loadNewSite();
    this.WebControl.autosize();
}

private void updateDoneTable() {
    ObservableList<UsedTableRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    data.addAll(datacontroller.getRowsFromEntity());

    this.DoneTable.getItems().clear();
    this.DoneTable.setItems(data);
}

private void loadNewSite() {

    Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    //Background work                       
                    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                WebControl.getEngine().load(webcontroller.getSelectedURL());
                                PAGE.setText((webcontroller.getIteratorAuctions() + webcontroller.getIteratorItems() - 10) + " z " + webcontroller.getItemsIds().size());
                            } finally {
                                latch.countDown();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    latch.await();
                    //Keep with the background work
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };

    service.start();



    /*  Task task = new Task(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WebControl.getEngine().load(webcontroler.getSelectedURL());
        }

    });
    tr.run();
    this.PAGE.setText((this.webcontroler.getIteratorAuctions() + this.webcontroler.getIteratorItems() - 10) + " z " + this.webcontroler.getItemsIds().size());
     */
}}
```

CInsurance Application class :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/cinsurance/MainWindow.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/cinsurance/mainwindow.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Aplikacja Ubezpieczeniowa CInsurance");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CInsurance.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In our application the `WebView` does not block the GUI.. but this line of code `data.addAll(datacontroller.getRowsFromEntity());` looks like it is doing a blocking database query? If yes, place if in a `Task` and you are good to go.

Comment: @eckig database control working like a charm , and it is separate module of application. But in your application WebView actions is in Application class or Controler class ? Maybe the place of WebView using is bad.. i must check it

Answer (score 0):

After i lost a lot of time on thinking why , i just continue to code modules for this application and i add some multithreading into initialize method of controller and ... it was very strange . Everything is working ok , even when i'm loading heavy page's. I still don't know why multithreading unlocks the blockade... but it can be also the change of JDK because i must change it to 32 bit form 64 bit. After all it is strange.